# React Accepting Value Prop ConsoleLog shows Different than Print on page

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing a very weird situation where I am accepting a prop within Square that comes from Board. I initialize it as value and am trying to give alert when user clicks on any number. This should be ideally very very simple though, while value shows on the board as 1, if I click on it, I get what you see object in the picture within function.

I am following React official tutorial 
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#completing-the-game

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because the way you implemented the onclick function there.It just lost the scope of the event. Please try with the code below.Replace the onClick function with this one.Hope it will work.
`onClick={()=>{console.log(data)}}`

Comment: Arrow function works if I do `onClick={()=>{console.log(value)}}`. Wonder what's different doing that and just function. Thank you

Comment: Difference is that arrow function remain in the existing class scope where using function(){} you are assigning a new scope which does not actually belong to the current event scope. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

onclick event handler has its own scope variable `value` . Which is an onclick event object. That is why you can't access value object is defined at render method level.

update event handler

```
onClick={function(e) { console.log(value); }}
```

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: if I am using a name that already exists like value, another name that I use should work?! I did `let malue = this.props.value;` and that tried to access malue, I still got a weird object... `this.props.value` is what I am sending from Board to Square so it should work like how it prints on the page weird. `function(e)` works though..